# Is any other way of accessing HTML:Textboxfor inside view in action Controller?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-mvc

I read JSON from URL and display as table format in MVC View DotnetCore.I have @Html.TextBoxFor control inside this same view under form control.

To display in table format, i have used both register @model and using statement inside view.So i can't able to access @Html.TextBoxFor values in controller action method.Is any way of accessing HTML:Textboxfor inside view in action Controller?

```
@model System.Data.DataTable 
@using System.Data;
```

No able to register namespace.models.model

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Admin", FormMethod.Post))
```

Need to access below control

```
{ @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.ImportJsonUrlName, new { id = "PickUrlID", style = "width:800px" })
```

On button click

```
<input type="submit" value="Import JSON" />
```

Display in table format

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-dark">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
            {
                <th>@col.ColumnName</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
        {
            <tr>
                @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)
                {
                    <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller code:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Index(AdminModel model)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string json = (new WebClient()).DownloadString("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wedeploy-examples/supermarket-web-example/master/products.json");
        dt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataTable>(json);
        return View(dt);
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you could return data from action and parse data in razor page. There are lots of excellent JQuery DataTables to load data. It can be easily rendered to add graphics or colour to your tables, as demonstrated in the example on this page.

Comment: @MichaelWang thanks for the response. Please kindly share me example link

Comment: You could try to google **jquery-bootgrid**  or [DataTables](https://datatables.net/manual/styling/classes).